# Google App Script variable is not fetching latest spreadsheet data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have written google app script method (stock alert) to get a specific stock based alert. My spreadsheet is refreshing  but variable

> data

value is fetching old `information` when I am calling the method. So my spreadsheet data got updated but when I run my method it's getting old spreadsheet data. I have used `SpreadsheetApp.flush();` but still, it's not getting latest data however if I run it after a certain period of time it's getting latest data somehow it's getting cached. Any idea to get latest data?

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Comment: Where is your setValues()?  It would be helpful to see a bit more of your script.

Comment: @Cooper when I am running my method data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); in this line data is returning old array and it's updating after certain time period. do you know any reason?

Comment: That's correct getValues() returns an array.  If you change the data in the array then you have to use setValues() to send it back to the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Cooper sorry for confusion  I am using GoogleFinance sheet method so my spreadsheet data is updating after certain interval and I can see data is updating in my sheet but when method is running its not getting latest updated array.